# Moving label under constraints

Tags: ios, xcode, uilabel, constraints, frame

I'm trying to move a label up and it's more complicated than anticipated.

Here is the required portion of the view :

[image: left side of my cell]

It's showing the number of unread messages and the date (we're in a xib here).

I'd like to see the date label vertically aligned with the middle of the white area on the right side, when there is no unread message.

I've got the "when there is no unread message." under control. So let's assume that the envelope and the number to its side aren't there and that *I just want to move my date label up programatically*.

I'm doing this, the frame is setting properly but nothing is moving. At all. i've even tried ridiculous numbers.

`lbDate` is my date label. 
`cell` is the current cell.

```
CGFloat newY = ((cell.frame.size.height/2)-(cell.lbDate.frame.size.height/2));
[cell.lbDate setFrame:CGRectMake(cell.lbDate.frame.origin.x, newY, cell.lbDate.frame.size.width, cell.lbDate.frame.size.height)];
```

So i'm guessing constraints have to do with this. I've tried putting one of the constraints as outlet (the vertical space between the envelope and my date label) and I simply set it to ridiculous values too but nothing moves.

What am I doing wrong? What should I do?

EDIT:
Apparently moving **both** the bottom and top constraints allowed me to move my label and I can now move it up properly.

Though when I re set it to its old initial values, it's somehow "stuck" to the envelope and they're WAY too close to each other.

Here is another code snippet :

```
if (unreadcount.intValue > 0){
        cell.lbUnreadMessages.hidden = NO;
        cell.imgEnvelope.hidden      = NO;
        cell.lbUnreadMessages.text   = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", unreadcount];

        cell.csLbDateToImgEnvelopeVertical.constant  = 0;   //Initial value
        cell.csLbDateBottomSpaceToSuperview.constant = 1;   //Initial value
    }else{
        cell.lbUnreadMessages.hidden = YES;
        cell.imgEnvelope.hidden      = YES;

        cell.csLbDateToImgEnvelopeVertical.constant  = -12;
        cell.csLbDateBottomSpaceToSuperview.constant = 13;
    }
```

Comment: You should do this by modifying the constraint's constant value, but I can't give you more specific advice without seeing what you've tried, and what constraints you have on all your subviews.

Comment: What is the clearer/best way for me to show you that? Should I just tick " show all constraints" in canvas and add another screenshot?

Comment: Maybe, I don't know what that will show. What's important are the vertical constraints on the label and how you make the envelope and number go away (are you hiding, removing?).

Comment: I edited my my answer with a bit more information

Comment: Why do you set the constant to 0 -- that will make it "stuck" to the envelope. Give it a larger value.

Comment: Oh it's just that yeah. Sometimes I write code without even thinking.
If you want some reputation feel free to write an answer and I'll validate it :)